# Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_ISVAILD(pHead->nBlockUse)

Tags: c++, scope, boost-asio

```
void Connection::Receive(){
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(read_buffer_),
          boost::bind(&Connection::handle_Receive, shared_from_this(),boost::asio::placeholders::error));
}

void Connection::handle_Receive(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  if(!error)
  {
      if(read_buffer_.size() <=0){
          read_buffer_.empty();
          this->Disconnect();
      }
        ByteBuffer b((std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>)read_buffer_.data(), read_buffer_.size());
        this->OnReceived(b);
        read_buffer_.empty();
  }
//when it loses the if(!error) scope the error pop-up
    }
```

Error:

```
Debug Assertion Faild!

Program: D:\C++\Server\Debug\Authsever.exe
File:f:\dd\vctools\crt_bld\self_x86\crt\src\dbgdel.cpp
Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_ISVAILD(pHead->nBlockUse)
```

when it loses the if(!error) scope the error pop-up, what is this error means?!

Comment: This error is normally caused by a double `delete` of some pointer.

Comment: @Sam Miller  boost::array<uint8_t, 1000> read_buffer_;

@Xeo am using smart ptrs so am not deleting any!!

Comment: @Mixed what makes you think you can cast the return type of boost::array<uint8_t,1000>::data() to a std::shared_ptr? That is likely the source of your double delete.

Comment: @Sam Miller so what do you recommend me to use instead of boost::array and i can cast it to std:shared_ptr?

Comment: @Mixed I recommend you read the documentation for both `boost::array` and `std::shared_ptr` since it seems you have no idea when or why to use either of them. I also have to idea what `ByteBuffer` is and why it needs a `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @Mixed I've turned my comment into an answer, you should probably ask a new question with your most recent comment. Ex: what type should I use for receiving data suitable for conversion into a `ByteBuffer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a double delete from casting a `uint8_t*` that is owned by a `boost::array<uint8_t,1000>` to a `std::shared_ptr`.

```
    ByteBuffer b((std::shared_ptr<uint8_t>)read_buffer_.data(), read_buffer_.size());
                                        ^^^^^
```

Don't do that, a `shared_ptr` is for pointers with dynamic storage duration.